# Angular2: Update Observables when child property changes (nested observables)

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following datatypes in my project:

- Project
- User

A project has many users. So I wrote a project service, which uses observables, to update the views. So far everything works fine, when a new project is created or a project is deleted.

Now I want to show the list of users, assigned to a particular project. The list should be updated as a new user is added or one gets deleted. How can this be done in Angular2 and RxJS?

```
class ProjectsService {
    public projects$: Observable<Project[]>;
    private projectsObserver: Observer<Project[]>;
    private dataStore: {
        projects: Project[]
    };

    addProject(p) {
        // Some magic server calls
        this.dataStore.projects.push(p);
        this.projectsObserver.next(this.dataStore.projects);
    }

    addUserToProject(p, u) {
        // Pseudo-Code and server calls
        // -> I want to use observables here
        p.users.push(u);
    }
}

class Projects {
    public users: Array<User>;
}

class User {
    public string userId;
    public string userName;
}
```

So basically I want to nest two observables. Is this the right way? Or are there other best practices?

I hope you understand my problem.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are doing is correct.

Where are you storing these objects? Are you using `@ngrx/store`?

Anyway you probably want to put the users array in a `*ngFor` loop, and in this case if you use the `async` pipe when reading the observable, you should probably see everything working.

I had a similar issue and my problem was that I was not using the async pipe.

Basically I would write something like this:

```
<ul>
 <li *ngFor="#user of (project | async)?.users">{{user.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Hope it helps

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html

Comment: Okay, thank you. I figured it out and learned a lot. Async pipe is really useful.